# Moving a Chrome tab to another Chrome window

Tags: chrome

**Scenario**

Let's say I have TabA and TabB in SourceWindow, and I want to move TabB to TargetWindow instead.

This becomes a bit of a hassle when doing it with mouse drag, if the source window is larger, and on top of the target window.

**Question**

I have a [plugin for simply detaching](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-windowpopup-keyboa/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) a tab into its own window, but now I'm looking for something that does the opposite; namely attach a tab to a specific window.

Is there such a plugin?